# execute mail once all item have been iterated

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following issues. 
I receive separate emails for each iteration of the loop. I want mail to be only sent once with all of the items iterated.

```
  <?php


  // Honey pot trap
  // Create a hidden input that is only visible to bots. If it's empty than proceed.
  if (empty($_POST['humancheck'])){
    // Proceeed if submit button have been pressed


      $fullName = $_POST['fname'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $stage = $_POST['stage'];


      include("db.php");

      $resources = "select * from resources where stage LIKE '%".$stage."%'";

      $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $resources);


      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {

        $data[] = array(
          'format' => $row['format'],
          'title' => $row['title'],
          'costs' => $row['cost'],
          'stage' => $row['stage'],
          'topic' => $row['topic'],
          'link' => $row['link']
        );
      }

      foreach($data as $item) {
        // Sanitize input data
        $clean_fullName = htmlspecialchars($fullName);
        $clean_email = htmlspecialchars($email);

        // Mail Set up
        $to = $clean_email;
        $to_us = "info@email.com";
        // Email subject
        $subject = "Your custom resource pack has arrived!";
        $subject_us = "New custom resource delivered to: $clean_email";

        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= "<p>";
        $message .= "Hi $clean_fullName, <br><br>";
        $message .= " Based on your responses, we have created a custom resource pack tailored to your needs.  <br><br>";
        $message .= "<b>{$item['title']}</b><br>";
        $message .= "{$item['format']} <br>";
        $message .= "{$item['costs']} <br>";
        $message .= "{$item['link']} <br><br>";

        $message .= " If you have any questions, do not hesitate to reach out to us.  <br><br>";
        $message .= "</p>";
        $message .= '</body></html>';

        $message_us = "The below message was sent to $clean_fullName <br>
                      <i>  Hi $clean_fullName <br>";
        $message_us .= "\r\n Based on your responses, we have created a custom resource pack tailored to your needs:  \r\n";
        $message_us .= "\r\n If you have any questions, do not hesitate to reach out to us.  \r\n";


        // Headers
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <info@email.com>' . "\r\n";

    }

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($to_us,$subject_us,$message_us,$headers);

  }


?>
```

what happens is the while loops to the data that is stored in an array. That array is used in foreach. and outside of the loops, the mail is suppose to mail the result.

In theory this should of worked but its not working.

Comment: with this indentation it's no wonder you are having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: the code you gave here is not the complete code. Any other loop is present in your code? We can see }} in the end of the code. Where do it starts?

Comment: sure il will update my code

Comment: i've made the edit to my post. hopefully its more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Edit last part of your code in this way. Take one time parameters of mail content outside the loop, and let loop make only the message content.

```
$clean_fullName = htmlspecialchars($fullName);
$clean_email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$to = $clean_email;
$to_us = "info@email.com";
$subject = "Your custom resource pack has arrived!";
$subject_us = "New custom resource delivered to: $clean_email";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= "<p>";
$message .= "Hi $clean_fullName, <br><br>";
$message .= " Based on your responses, we have created a custom resource pack tailored to your needs.  <br><br>";

foreach($data as $item) {

$message .= "<b>{$item['title']}</b><br>";
$message .= "{$item['format']} <br>";
$message .= "{$item['costs']} <br>";
$message .= "{$item['link']} <br><br>";

}

$message .= " If you have any questions, do not hesitate to reach out to us.  <br><br>";
$message .= "</p>";
$message .= '</body></html>';
$message_us = "The below message was sent to $clean_fullName <br><i>  Hi $clean_fullName <br>";
$message_us .= "\r\n Based on your responses, we have created a custom resource pack tailored to your needs:  \r\n";
$message_us .= "\r\n If you have any questions, do not hesitate to reach out to us.  \r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <info@email.com>' . "\r\n";


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($to_us,$subject_us,$message_us,$headers);
```